# Excel Graph Auto-Adaptative

Tags: excel, if-statement, graph, offset, vba

I have a problem. I have a graph with 2 columns.

One is the dates, the other is figures.

```
12/12    100
13/12    150
14/12    180
```

Actually inside each cells there is a formula =if(Sheet1!A1= "","", B1*C1)
etc... so my 2 columns got only 3 "filled" with numbers rows, but there is actually formula for around 20 rows.

Now I am trying to do an auto-adaptive graph. I just want the graph to take the now dates and numbers.

The problem is, with regualar way to do it with name manager OFFSET ((=OFFSET('Sheet2'!$F$9,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet2'!$F:$F)) , it will also take the blank cells where there is formulas inside too...

How to do?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing your empty string with the NA function:  =if(Sheet1!A1= "",NA(), B1*C1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still not working. Exactly the dates are made with an =offset formula and the number with an IF formula with a sumifs inside.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: Sure. I want to graphe those two series with an Auto-Adjust graph. In the cells there is formulas.Some pop up figures, other nothing (if A1="","" for example)  For Dates its an offset formula, for the number it is an if formula with inside a sumif. 

My graph do not auto-adapt to the size of the data, it takes even the white cells where there is inside formulas. I do a bar chart. So at the end there is 3 bar in the barchart at the left and a huge space at the right. I would like to take only the datas.

Comment: Try using NA() in your formulas as I mentioned, then in your named range formula replace your COUNTA with COUNTIF('Sheet2'!$F:$F,"<>#N/A")